# ASP.NET Core - saving data into Excel workbook doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, export-to-excel, excelpackage

I have an ASP.NET Core web app with a `FilteredStockTableList` on my page. I want it to export this to an Excel file and have it downloaded automatically with a button on my `.cshtml` page. However nothing is prompted on the browser, although the button is successfully clicked.

Here's my button on that `.cshtml` page:

```
<button id="exportButton" asp-action="ExportToExcel" 
        class="btn btn-primary">Export to Excel</button>
```

Here's my `ExportToExcel` method:

```
public IActionResult ExportToExcel(List<StockTable> FilteredStockTableList)
{
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("StockTableData");

        // Set headers
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Site";
        worksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Floor";
        worksheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "RowIndex";
        worksheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "Code";
        worksheet.Cells["E1"].Value = "Size";
        worksheet.Cells["F1"].Value = "NeededQuantity";
        worksheet.Cells["G1"].Value = "Stock2";
        worksheet.Cells["H1"].Value = "Stock1";
        worksheet.Cells["I1"].Value = "Stock3";
        worksheet.Cells["J1"].Value = "Purchase";
        worksheet.Cells["K1"].Value = "VersionNumber";

        for (int i = 0; i < FilteredStockTableList.Count; i++)
        {
            var stock = FilteredStockTableList[i];

            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = stock.Site;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = stock.Floor;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = stock.RowIndex;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = stock.Code;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 5].Value = stock.Size;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 6].Value = stock.NeededQuantity;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 7].Value = stock.Stock2;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 8].Value = stock.Stock1;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 9].Value = stock.Stock3;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 10].Value = stock.Purchase;
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, 11].Value = stock.VersionNumber;
        }

        var contentDisposition = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                {
                    FileName = "StockTableData.xlsx",
                    Inline = false,
                };

        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            package.SaveAs(stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `StockTable` class:

```
public class StockTable
{
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string Floor { get; set; }
    public string RowIndex { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public int NeededQuantity { get; set; }
    public int Stock2 { get; set; }
    public int Stock1 { get; set; }
    public int Stock3 { get; set; }
    public int Purchase { get; set; }
    public int VersionNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When using your code I get a Closed Stream Error.  Use `var stream = new MemoryStream();` instead of `using (var stream = new MemoryStream())`